# Explicit conversion from Single to Decimal results in different bit representation

Tags: c#, types, floating-point, decimal, primitive-types

If I convert **single** *s* into **decimal** *d* I've noticed it's bit representation differs from that of the decimal created directly.

For example:

```
Single s = 0.01f;
Decimal d = 0.01m;

int[] bitsSingle = Decimal.GetBits((decimal)s)
int[] bitsDecimal = Decimal.GetBits(d)
```

Returns (middle elements removed for brevity):

> ```
> bitsSingle:
> [0] = 10
> [3] = 196608
>
> bitsDecimal:
> [0] = 1
> [3] = 131072
> ```

Both of these are decimal numbers, which both (appear) to be accurately representing 0.01:

[image]

Looking at the spec sheds no light except perhaps:

> §4.1.7 Contrary to the float and double data types, decimal fractional
>   numbers such as 0.1 can be represented exactly in the decimal
>   representation.

Suggesting that this is somehow affected by **single** not being able accurately represent 0.01 before the conversion, therefore:

- Why is this not accurate by the time the conversion is done?
- Why do we seem to have two ways to represent 0.01 in the same datatype?

Comment: I've come across some code that relies on the result of `Decimal.GetBits()`, but aside from that I think this is interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Both decimals precisely represent 0.1. It's just that the `decimal` format, allows multiple bitwise-different values that represent the exact same number.

#### Explanation

It isn't about `single` not being able to represent 0.1 precisely. As per the documentation of `GetBits`:

> The binary representation of a `Decimal` number consists of a 1-bit
>   sign, a 96-bit integer number, and a scaling factor used to divide the
>   integer number and specify what portion of it is a decimal fraction.
>   The scaling factor is implicitly the number 10, raised to an exponent
>   ranging from 0 to 28.
>
> The return value is a four-element array of 32-bit signed integers.
>
> The first, second, and third elements of the returned array contain
>   the low, middle, and high 32 bits of the 96-bit integer number.
>
> The fourth element of the returned array contains the scale factor and
>   sign. It consists of the following parts:
>
> Bits 0 to 15, the lower word, are unused and must be zero.
>
> Bits 16 to 23 must contain an exponent between 0 and 28, which
>   indicates the power of 10 to divide the integer number.
>
> Bits 24 to 30 are unused and must be zero.
>
> Bit 31 contains the sign: 0 mean positive, and 1 means negative.
>
> Note that the bit representation differentiates between negative and
>   positive zero. These values are treated as being equal in all
>   operations.

The fourth integer of each `decimal` in your example is `0x00030000` for `bitsSingle` and `0x00020000` for `bitsDecimal`. In binary this maps to:

```
bitsSingle     00000000 00000011 00000000 00000000
               |\-----/ \------/ \---------------/
               |   |       |             |
        sign <-+ unused exponent       unused
               |   |       |             |
               |/-----\ /------\ /---------------\
bitsDecimal    00000000 00000010 00000000 00000000

NOTE: exponent represents multiplication by negative power of 10
```

Therefore, in the first case the 96-bit integer is divided by an additional factor of 10 compared to the second -- bits 16 to 23 give the value 3 instead of 2. But that is offset by the 96-bit integer itself, which in the first case is also 10 times greater than in the second (obvious from the values of the first elements).

The difference in observed values can therefore be attributed simply to the fact that the conversion from `single` uses subtly different logic to derive the internal representation compared to the "straight" constructor.

Comment: Better answer than mine, in that its correct. Can be easily asserted by testing `0.01m.Equals((decimal)0.01f));`, analgously, `1/100`, `10/1000`, `0.01`, `1%`, `1 * 10^-2` and `10 * 10^-3` are all representations of the same number.

Comment: Although 0.01m and (decimal)0.01f are mathematically equal, calling `ToString` on them produces different results. So the two are not entirely equivalent.

Comment: @MichaelLiu: What exactly does your comment refer to?

Comment: I'm not criticizing your answer in any way. I'm just noting (in answer to the OP's second question) that there is actually a meaningful difference in the various ways of representing 0.1 as a decimal.

Comment: @MichaelLiu: No worries, I just couldn't place what you were referring to. It seems that `decimal.ToString` also uses the exponent to decide how many decimal places to show (very logical), although as you can't predict what the cast will result in you can't really call that a feature IMO.

Comment: @MichaelLiu: I wonder if the values are intended to be semantically significant, or if `Decimal` behaves as it does because adding two values which have the same number of digits after the decimal is much faster than adding values with different numbers of digits after; not only would removing the trailing zero from the sum of .37 plus 0.43 take a fair amount of time, but it would then increase the time required to add another value with two digits to the right of the decimal.